# Should a LoggedinDTO contain the user password

Tags: c#, api

I have built an API which can log an user in and if sucessfull it returns a DTO. Should I include the password in the DTO or isnt that neccessary?

Comment: First, you shouldn't store passwords at all but rather hashes of passwords

Comment: Alright I was just wondering. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: A DTO to what? The login screen has to submit the password to the api controller one way or another. Is that what you mean DTO? *That* DTO needs the password. Passwords shouldn't be stored either in cleartext or encrypted form. They should be salted and hashed (a few thousand times) using a cryptographically strong algorithm. So the DTO from the controller to the database shouldn't contain the password, only the hash.

Comment: I meant what the user gets back after a succesfull login. So i have the model but I don't want to return the whole model but I was wondering if it needs a password in it but now I understand why .